# Linear probing Hash Tables insertion

Tags: c, hashtable

==3139== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

==3139==    at 0x4A0673F: strcpy (mc_replace_strmem.c:311)

==3139==    by 0x400ADB: htable_insert (hashtable.c:56)

==3139==    by 0x400F25: main (mylib.c:11)

Hi everybody, I'm still trying to insert into a hash table. I can't quite get it to work, i've included my print method, just because i thought it might be a problem. I'm trying to do linear probing. When I ran valgrind, I got this error, I think it has something to do with copying into my string, but I'm not really sure what is means? I really don't at this point know how to get this insertion working, some input would be wonderful..
Line 56 in hashtable insert is strcpy(str, key)

```
int htable_insert(htable h, char *str) {
   int i;
   /*convert string to integer*/
   unsigned int index = htable_word_to_int(str);
   /*calculate index to insert into hash table*/
   int remainder = index%h->capacity;
   /*once calculated position in the hash table, 3 possibilities occur*/
   /*no string in this positon, copy string to that position, increment number of keys, return 1*/
   if (h->key[remainder] == NULL) {
      char *key = emalloc(strlen(str) + 1);
      strcpy(str, key);
      h->key[remainder] = key;
      h->frequencies[remainder] = 1;
      h->num_keys++;
      return 1;
   }
   /*the exact same string is at the position, increment frequency at that position, return frequency*/
   if (strcmp(str, h->key[remainder]) == 0) {
      h->frequencies[remainder]++;
      return h->frequencies[remainder];
   }/*a string is at that position, but it isnt the rightone, keep moving along the array
      until you find either an open space or the string you are looking for*/
   if (h->key[remainder] != NULL && strcmp(str, h->key[remainder]) != 0) {
      /*you may need to wrap back around to the beginning of the table, so each time you add
        to the position you should also mod by the table capacity.*/
      for (i = 0; i <= h->capacity; i++) {
         /*no string in this positon, copy string to that position, increment number of keys*/
         if (h->key[remainder] == NULL) {
            char *key = emalloc(strlen(str) + 1);
            strcpy(str, key);
            h->key[remainder] = key;
            h->frequencies[remainder] = 1;
            h->num_keys++;
         }
         /*if you find the string you were looking for, increment the frequecny at the position
           and return the frequency*/
         if (strcmp(str, h->key[remainder]) == 0) {
            h->frequencies[remainder]++;
            return h->frequencies[remainder];
         }
         if (h->key[remainder] != NULL && h->capacity ==  i) {
            i = 0;
         }
      }   
   }
   /*if you have kept looking for an open space but there isnt one, the hash table must fu*/
   return 0;
}

void htable_print(htable h, FILE *stream) {
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < h->capacity; i++) {
      if(h->key[i] != NULL) {
         fprintf(stream, "%d%s\n", h->frequencies[i], h->key[i]);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your strcpy's should be strcpy(key, str) and not the other way around. (You can just use strdup, btw, and save the malloc+strcpy).

Also, in:
   if (h->key[remainder] != NULL && strcmp(str, h->key[remainder]) != 0) {

The condition "h->key[remainder] != NULL" is redundant: you've already checked that above.

Finally, in your loop (going over the buckets), it seems like:

1. The loop condition should be <, not <=
2. You should be incrementing remainder somewhere, or use "remainder+i" and the index to h->keys
3. Instead of "capacity==i" --> "i=0", just use "(remainder+i)%capacity" as the index to h->keys

.. Finally finally -- the initial part, the one that's outside the loop, could be in the loop, saving code.

Comment: Okay so i changed the loop condition, and the copying thing. what you're saying at 2 and 3 confused me a little bit.

Comment: "The condition "h->key[remainder] != NULL" is redundant" -- **Both** conditions are redundant.

Comment: "what you're saying at 2 and 3 confused me a little bit" -- `remainder` is the slot index calculated from the hash code. You check for whether that slot is empty or already has the key. If not, you loop looking for an empty slot ... but you never change the slot index, always looking at the same one. Be sure to test your code with strings that hit the same slot. BTW, there are much better hash table algorithms; once you master this code, you might want to investigate the technology.